# Ethernet raw data and Frame Check Sequence in C

Tags: c, protocols, checksum, packet, ethernet

I'm trying to build a raw data with ethernet frame via C code.
I built a packet (included Ethernet->IP->UDP->DHCP protocols) and sent it via the WiFi interface. I followed it via the Wireshark which prints out: 
Ethernet2 -> Frame Check Sequence -> Incorrect, should be XXX.

I did not build an FCS data in my packet, I left the field blank. 
Now, I can't find any simple function/code in C which does that. All the codes I found gave me a bad output.

Someone done it before and can share how to implement the FCS in the Ethernet packet?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: This looks more like a request for a library which is also off-topic.

Comment: Most (if not all) Ethernet MACs will generate the FCS in hardware. However, user-space programs in general computers usually can't write link-layer packets - raw sockets start at network-layer (IP) - therefore I'm assuming you have an embedded system or some kernel module for this task, which is relevant and should be mentioned in the question for proper help.

Answer (score 2):

FIX: it seems that FCS calculation is only optional, I added the IP checksum calculation instead and that was enough for the DHCP to pass.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
#define BYTE unsigned char
     int fcs(BYTE* paquete,int n){
        int byte,sum=0;
        n++;
        for(int j=0;j<=n;j++){
                byte=paquete[j];
                for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
                        if(j!=n && i<7){
                                sum = sum+(byte & 0x01);
                                byte = byte >> 1;
                        }
                }
        }
        return sum;
}
```